# FBI files for people background template

Tags: page-layout

I need to create a report like FBI reports for people background.
can anyone give me a link to such a paper so I can design it or give me its template?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest Googling terms like 'FBI report', 'character profile' or 'personal intelligence file'. You should come up with a good number of images to go through and get some idea of what the layout should be like.

Comment: I'm sure _that_ won't raise any flags... ;-)